# Central login page - different portals (SP2010)

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth, architecture, public-website

I would like to have some advice for the logical structure for a corporate portal.
I really appreciate your feedback.

### **AS IS**

At the moment we have a 'partly' public facing site. Assuming this site is currently available via https://**audience1**.mydomain.com. Anonymous access is enabled for this site, but most of its content is only visible for authenticated users (Win & Form/Claim Based). Anonymous users are able to register at this site, via a registration form and are able to log on via a login box. This webapplication contains of just 1 site collection.

### **TO BE**

In the future we want a new entry https://**audience2**.mydomain.com, which will contain different information (for a different audience) and later on, we also would like to create a 'full' public facing website (http://mydomain.com).

### **QUESTION**

At our future public facing website (http://mydomain.com) - we would like to have a central login box. After a user logs in and clicks on the **audience1** or **audience2** hyperlink, we would like to prevent the user to log in again.

Which setup do you prefer in this case? And why?

- 3 webapplications (each of them contains 1 site collection) is it even possible to pass credentials (Form based) from one webapplication to another. In a pure ASP.NET application, it seems possible (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)
- 1 webapplication (3 host-named sitecollections) - http://zoom.it/rQ2u#full
- Other options?

Thanks in advance, guys!
Greetings